# How to create view that extracts min and max XY coordinates

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to create a view that displays a suburb name, ssc code and min & max XY. Current code gives me ALL the coordinates but I don't know how to adjust it to select the min and max without getting error after error.

```
CREATE  VIEW V_SUBURBBOUNDS AS
SELECT s.suburb_id, s.ssc_code, s.suburb, v.arc_id, v.x_coord, v.y_coord
FROM SUBURB_ATTRIBUTE s,
     SUBURB_VERTEX v,
     SUBURB_ARC a
WHERE a.arc_id=v.arc_id
   OR a.left_poly=s.suburb_id
   OR a.right_poly=s.suburb_id
```

Do I need to do a join to that specific table to extract them?

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need  aggreation function and group  by

```
CREATE  VIEW V_SUBURBBOUNDS AS
SELECT s.suburb_id, s.ssc_code, s.suburb, v.arc_id
  , min(v.x_coord) min_x, min(v.y_coord) min_y
  , max(v.x_coord) max_x, max(v.y_coord) max_y
FROM  SUBURB_ARC a
INNER JOIN SUBURB_ATTRIBUTE s ON ( a.left_poly=s.suburb_id  OR a.right_poly=s.suburb_id)
INNER JOIN SUBURB_VERTEX v ON a.arc_id=v.arc_id
GROUP BY s.suburb_id, s.ssc_code, s.suburb, v.arc_id
```

and you should explicit JOIN syntax (instead of the old implicit join syntax based  on where )